# generate bank account number with random

Tags: java

i have a question :
I can find no explanation on how to generate in java a bank account in the format: BE00 0000 0000 0000. BE must stay and the 0 must be generated randomly. For exemple : BE96 4567 7896 4789.
Sorry for my english, i'm French.
Thanks in advance. Have a nice day

Comment: Try to rephrase your question in a more generic way. In other words, what you want to do is create a random string consisting of `BE` and 14 random numbers. Find out how to generate a random number and append it to a string, 14 times.

Comment: What did you try so far? You can create a string, make first 2 chars BE and use random to randomize rest.

Comment: Generating at random valid IBAN account numbers, is really complex. IBAN account numbers vary in length between European countries (they are shorter in Germany than in Monaco, for example). The validation rules for an IBAN account number are available though, also as a Java library.

Comment: try to use a random index from the string `1234567890`

Comment: If you are going to store data in database and going to generate ids in several instances of application you'd better use database utilities to generate unique key values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the validity of the number generated you can try something like this.

What it does is, I've created a `String` with initial value of `BE`, afterwards kept adding a random integer from `[0,9]` 14 times. This way now I have a string with the format you've wanted.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Random rand = new Random();
    String card = "BE";
    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
    {
        int n = rand.nextInt(10) + 0;
        card += Integer.toString(n);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        if(i % 4 == 0)
          System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(card.charAt(i));
    }
  }
}
```

Example output(s):

```
BE69 5987 1676 6052
BE06 8159 1742 2133
BE36 6723 4210 0408
BE74 4759 6874 6751
```

<strike>You can split your string each `4` characters, so that it'll look exactly as you wanted.</strike>

Now I've updated the code with a simple demonstration of how to split the `String` each `4` characters. I'm not really familiar with Java, so pardon my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Random class to generate the numbers.

`java.util.Random;`

You can save it as a string and append the numbers.

```
public class BankNum {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String start = "BE";
        Random value = new Random();

    //Generate two values to append to 'BE'
    int r1 = value.nextInt(10);
    int r2 = value.nextInt(10);
    start += Integer.toString(r1) + Integer.toString(r2) + " ";

    int count = 0;
    int n = 0;
    for(int i =0; i < 12;i++)
    {
        if(count == 4)
        {
            start += " ";
            count =0;
        }
        else 
            n = value.nextInt(10);
            start += Integer.toString(n);
            count++;            

    }
    System.out.println(start);
}
}
```

Possible Output:

```
BE74 7720 0458 8016
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use [Apache Common Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library,

There is a utility class: [RandomUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomUtils.html) which can help you generate variant kinds of random values.

and another utility class: [RandomStringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html) which can generate random string.

I think you can use [RandomStringUtils#randomNumeric](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html#randomNumeric-int-)